# How to display 'userUnemployment' in the message box when certain choices are picked in the Userform

Tags: excel, vba

I want to display the unemployment numbers for the specific year and race chosen by the user in a Userform. The userUnemployment will be static numbers that specific to certain conditions being met.

I have tried various If and Else, If and ElseIfs

```
Private Sub buttonOk_Click()
Dim year, race As String
Dim userUnemployment As String
```

'first find the year

```
If five Then
     year = "2005"
ElseIf six Then
     year = "2006"
ElseIf seven Then
     year = "2007"
ElseIf eight Then
     year = "2008"
ElseIf nine Then
     year = "2009"
ElseIf ten Then
     year = "2006"
ElseIf eleven Then
     year = "2007"
ElseIf twelve Then
     year = "2008"
ElseIf thirteen Then
     year = "2009"
ElseIf fourteen Then
     year = "2009"
ElseIf fifteen Then
     year = "2006"
ElseIf sixteen Then
     year = "2007"
ElseIf seventeen Then
     year = "2008"
ElseIf eighteen Then
     year = "2009"
End If
```

'now find the race for that year

```
If white Then
    race = "white"
ElseIf black Then
    race = "black"
ElseIf hispanic Then
    race = "hispanic"
ElseIf asian Then
    race = "asian"
End If
```

'now find the unemployment rate for the things specified

```
If year = "2005" & race = "white" Then
         userUnemployment = "3.48"
ElseIf year = "2005" & race = "black" Then
         userUnemployment = "5"

End If

  MsgBox ("The year is " + year + ", and your race is " + userUnemployment + " " + race)






 End Sub
```

I want the message to display the userUnemployment number specified. I only listed two choices because I have not found the other unemployment numbers I want to use yet. So as long as I can get it to work for those two then I can figure the rest out.

Comment: What does your MsgBox display now? or do you get an error?

Comment: My message displays everything except it completely skips the userUnemployment number

Comment: The message displays "The Year is 2005, and your race is  white" It includes the extra space between race and white but it does not display the userUnemployment number

Comment: Try changing `&` to `And`. `&` is primarily used for concatenating strings

Comment: The year is 2019, and we're apparently still putting humans in color-coded boxes.

Answer (score 1):

On a worksheet (I used Sheet1), create a table like this to hold your Unemployment Rates (Note that I only populated the values that you provided in your question):

[image]

You haven't shown what your userform looks like, but I assume it's got Option Buttons (radio buttons) for selecting the Year and the Race.  In general, for this use case, a much cleaner solution would instead to use either Listboxes or Comboboxes.  I decided to use Listboxes for this example.  My userform looks like this:

[image]

And here is the full userform code.  The `UserForm_Initialize` code populates the listboxes based on the table.  Then the `btnOK_Click()` verifies that a Year and a Race have been selected and then finds the corresponding Unemployment Rate using a VLookup.  It then outputs a MsgBox displaying the results:

```
Private Sub btnCancel_Click()

    Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub btnOK_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sRace As String
    Dim lYear As Long
    Dim lRaceCol As Long
    Dim dUnemployment As Double

    If Me.listYear.ListIndex = -1 Then
        Me.listYear.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Must select a year.", , "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.listRace.ListIndex = -1 Then
        Me.listRace.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Must select a race.", , "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    lYear = Me.listYear.List(Me.listYear.ListIndex)
    sRace = Me.listRace.List(Me.listRace.ListIndex)

    dUnemployment = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lYear, ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, WorksheetFunction.Match(sRace, ws.Rows(1), 0), False)

    MsgBox "Year: " & lYear & Chr(10) & _
           "Race: " & sRace & Chr(10) & _
           "Unemployment Rate: " & dUnemployment

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Me.listYear.List = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value
    Me.listRace.List = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("B1", ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Value)

End Sub
```

Here's what it looks like in action:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use the msgbox like this:  "Msgbox = "The year is " & year & " and your race is " & usereunemployment".  This should display the message that you want to see....

Comment: Is the equals sign a typo?

Comment: Removing the parenthesis does not change anything. It displays the whole message except for completely disregarding the userUnemployment number.

Comment: @Mistella.........Yes...............typo on my part